# GraphQL: Query performance and data fetch order

Tags: sql, performance, graphql

I know that GraphQL's primary behavior is all about having a single endpoint to query the data.

How does filters work in GraphQL query? Does it first get the whole data from the Database into the memory and then filter based on the query conditions?
Can anyone please clarify on this?

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is just the query language for the API, it does not specify the implementation of the logic behind the API, that's up to you.

If you want to set up filtering in GraphQL, I would recommend doing so as much as possible at the database level to avoid having to load a large an unnecessary amount of data into memory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
As per your comment, can I understand that GraphQL queries fetch the whole data before applying the query conditions into the memory and then apply the conditions?
Please confirm.

Comment: No, GraphQL does not apply the filtering at all, it doesn't handle anything with the actual data fetching. That's up to you in your implementation of the API.

Comment: Thanks again.
But what happens in the below case?

query MyQuery {
  sk_test(where: {TestRelation: {Ref_Name: {_is_null: false}}}) {
    ID
    NAME
    TestRelation {
      Ref_Name
    }
  }
}

I have give some where condition for this query.

Comment: GraphQL will translate that to types in your server language and you have to implement the resolver, so it's up to you what happens